# Database server

Tags: mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I am going to make an Internet project. The sizes of it I don't know now. But I want to ask some questions. :
1. What database system is better? ( MySql or other )
2. What is more useful CPU or RAM?
3. What server is better for database server ( i5-2500 (4 x 3.2Ghz) and 16 GB Ram or Xeon E5330 (8 x 2.1Ghz) and 8 GB Ram )?

I think that read queries will be more then input/update and of course with joins.

Comment: Hello. This question is essentially a shopping question, which is off-topic for all sites on the Stack Exchange network - see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more info. "Better" entirely subjective, depends on your budget, same with CPU and RAM. I'd suggest you start basic and then worry about the load.

Comment: They have the internet on computers now?

Comment: Read our FAQ before posting next time please.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever technologies you're most comfortable with.

Figure out how your application demands resources, and then find the best fit for that based on what server solutions are available.

There's no way to prove which is better in terms of processor specification without doing a side-by-side benchmark using your application.

Comment: OK, who downvoted me. Own up.